# R: tm package reading in Newsgroups data

Tags: r, tm, newsgroup

The lines of code below return the following error:

">"object 'readNewsgroup' not found

```
library(tm)
setwd("C:/Users/DanRoDuq/Downloads/20news-bydate-train")
sci.electr.train=Corpus(DirSource("sci.electronics")
,readerControl=list(reader=readNewsgroup,language="en_US"))
```

I got the data from: http://qwone.com/~jason/20Newsgroups/lexData.text, and downloaded the file called 20news-bydate.tar.gz

When I replace readNewsgroup by readPlain, the code runs, but the instructions I'm following tell me to use the readNewsGroup setting. Should I maybe be loading another library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no longer a reader called `readNewsgroup` in the current `tm`-Version (0.6).
With `getReaders()` you get all available readers for your Version.

Download the same Version as the instructions you are following and there should be a 
`readNewsgroup` reader.